# Disable of items in NSComboBox

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nscombobox

I have an `NSComboBox` with some values. Is there any way by which I can disable a few items? I want some values to be enabled and some disabled. Is it possible?

Comment: why don't you simply remove them from the data source?

Comment: you can also observe the index of the selecteded item and select another one in case of a invalid index selection.

Comment: Hi Leo, thanks for the suggestion. I had already thought of the removal from datasource, but  i would like to disable the items and not remove it completely. Is there any way out for that?

Comment: The options you have I already commented above. You can't disable any of them but you can select a different one in case you don't want to allow the user to select it